# Howto create a Bootstrap3 nav-tabs whose tabs have different font-sizes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's an example JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/731/edit

I pulled this example almost verbatim from the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li class="pull-right smaller-text"><a href="#">Screwed Up Tab/Floats above</a></li>
</ul>
```

The two changes I made were to pull-right class, and add a smaller-text class which is defined simply as:

```
.smaller-text {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

The issue with having different font-sizes, is it creates a gap in the smaller-sized tabs:

[image: Gab in the smaller-sized tab screenshot]

I can play with line-height options for the tab to try and make the tab almost the same height, but I just can't quite get the tab bottom to be flush with the content below.

Thanks in advance!

***Edit***

I was able to extrapolate a bootstrap3/less based upon djbhindi's answer below, to be pretty generic.

My CSS (in less/bootstrap) looks like this:

```
  li.tab a {
   font-size: ceil((@font-size-base * 1.25));    
  }

  li.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    top: (ceil(((@line-height-computed * 1.25) - (floor(@font-size-small * @line-height-small) * 1.25))) + 1);

    a {
      line-height: @line-height-computed * 1.25; // fix the gap for the tabs & match with the normal tabs
    }
  }
```

The respective HTML looks similar to this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="position: relative;">
  <li class="tab active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li class="tab pull-right dropdown"><a href="#"><small>Screwed Up Tab/Floats above</small></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in the CSS file, which assumes a larger font size (you changed it from something larger to 10px right?).

So all you have to do there is adjust what is probably a relative positioning tag; it would say something like:

```
position:relative;
top:20px;
```